# Unexpected token, expected "," react

Tags: reactjs

Hello every body I have some trouble with this code , when compiled I get the following error :
**Unexpected token, expected "," (5:58)**

Any clue ?

```
import React from 'react';
const MyComponent = (data) => {
  console.log(data);
  
  return (
  <div>
      {}
  </div>    );
};

const data = {
  apple: 1,
  mango: 2,
  banana:3
};


ReactDOM.render(
     <MyComponent {...data} />      
     document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: You are missing a "," after ``<MyComponent ... />``

Comment: Thank you for your help Tracer69 ;-) is is normal that the code doesnt display anything ?

Comment: It literally says ``expected ","``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a "," after `<MyComponent/>`

Comment: Thank you for your help George Sepetadelis ;-) is is normal that the code doesnt display anything ?

Comment: @Abdelkader I can not know this, you have to ask a new question about this problem. If my answer help you please accept it :-)

Comment: ok I will post a new question and also I accepted your answer